# How do I find the source of my furnace's condensate leak?

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace, central-heating

I bought a house in November that had a brand new high efficiency furnace put in sometime in the summer. There is water coming out of the furnace and not the drain pipe.

Is this a clog in the pipe or something more serious?

Also, there are a couple of drops forming at points on the flue exhaust pipe.

Link to photo because file size is too big: https://imgur.com/a/oBJVKyC

Comment: Is "HE" short for "High Efficiency" or a typo for "GE" or something else? Always helpful to spell out your acronyms the first time, especially on an international web site where terms aren't necessarily common across continents.

Comment: Edited to high efficiency!

Comment: Is the furnace also an air conditioner?  While it seems clear from the question, please confirm this is winter condensate from the high efficiency furnace flue, and not summer condensate from the A/C evaporator?

Comment: It would be helpful if you include photos of the entire condensate path, inside and outside the furnace. One of the far side where (apparently) the condensate pipe is, one of the inside left wall (the same area but behind the cover), one showing where water is collecting inside the furnace.   Wait til you see water (not just stains) on the floor, turn off the power, open the cover, and take as many pictures as possible inside and out showing where the water SHOULD be and where it is.

Comment: I believe it is also an air conditioner. I assume winter condensate as we're not running the air conditioner since it's winter here. Photos here of the condensate inside the covers: https://imgur.com/a/SjgO3er. Appears to be coming from the first picture around where the gray condensate drain line connects to the white plastic piece with the beige connector

Comment: They lost the rubber elbow and its two hose clamps and used some random elbow. It shouldn't be glued. No idea where you'd get the elbow. It comes in the bespoke drain parts kit that comes with a new furnace.

Answer (score 0):

First check is to see if there is any condensation coming out of the PVC drain.  If there is some, then it's likely just a partially clogged drain line.  If it's completely dry (and doesn't show any indication of moisture), then it's possible that it wasn't installed properly.  I believe there is typically an air gap/vent where the PVC drain line exits the furnace.  Check there to see if there is any water present there (either spilling out, or in the pipe if you can see into it), and that will also help identify if the condensation is even leaving your furnace.

But, if the unit was installed this summer, there should be an installation/parts warrantee that's still valid.  I'd suggest contacting the installer to fix the issue under warrantee.

Comment: And for your condensation on the exhaust pipe; are you sure it's the exhaust pipe?  Many/most HE furnaces pull air from outside for combustion, so if you have 2 PVC pipes going to the furnace, then likely one is incoming combustion air, and the other is exhaust air.  The exhaust one will probably be warm to the touch when the furnace is running.  The incoming combustion air might get a bit of condensation on it, depending on incoming air temperature from the outside, and indoor humidity level.

Comment: There is condensate coming from the drain pipe so maybe just a partial clog. It's definitely the exhaust - the pipe goes outside of the house and is warm to the touch when the furnace is on. Pics here of the condensate on the exhaust: https://imgur.com/a/EKbalHb

Comment: Wow, those pictures don't show any signs of PVC glue (though some glue could be clear, I guess).  I wonder if all of that PVC is just press-fit?  If so, it certainly was a hack job install.  All of those joints should be glued, as it looks like those drips are coming from the joints, which would be typical and expected if they aren't glued.  It's not a high pressure output, but that dripping sure looks like the joints are unsealed.  If any of those joints are not glued, it could leak combustion byproducts into your house as well.  Definitely needs to be fixed ASAP.

Comment: Makes sense. Appreciate the help!

Comment: If this is correct, if the flue pipes are unglued, you should have an experienced plumber check the entire installation with a microscope, urgently. Every detail.  And buy some CO detectors, right now, today for this room and the bedrooms.

Answer (score 0):

Rubber elbow that you cut the end off, depending on the unit's orientation. Secured with two hose clamps, not a pressure fit PVC elbow.

[image]

https://www.hvacpartsshop.com/337668-701-condensate-part/